# App logo for python tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have a file.ico file that I want to put as my logo for the application. It is similar to favicon in html.

This is the ending code:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Blacky Birds")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.configure(bg="forestgreen")
game = SqBoard(root, width=16, height=16, letters=10)
game.mainloop()
```

I am not sure but an guessing that it will be in this part of my file. Should be a one liner like root.icon(PhotoImage(file.ico)) or something similar. Please help me out. I am using Python 3.4.2 with Tkinter as Gui. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root.iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
```